# Image generation in progress. Try again shortly. (503 service unavailable)

Tags: 7, media

I have two exact copies of the same code installed in the same server running a common AMP stack (I am using bitnami). One copy is named as 'dev' and another one is 'prod'.

Only they have their own database & files (which are clones as well).

In dev, Image styles work just fine. I do `drush if` - it deletes the styles and creates when viewed.

But in prod, drupal throws `503 service unavailable` with a `Image generation in progress. Try again shortly.` content on the first hit (or until the image is generated).

Of-course that comes from `image.module` line 858, when drupal finds a `lock`. And somehow setting `image_allow_insecure_derivatives` to TRUE might solve this issue.

What I don't understand is why its happening! And whats the remedy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it!

It was a server configuration issue ([PageSpeed (bitnami)](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache/PageSpeed#How_to_check_if_mod_pagespeed_is_already_enabled.3f) to be specific).

I `tail -f`ed the access log and saw

```
xxx.my.ip.xxx - - .... "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36"

xxx.server.ip.xxx - - .... "Serf/1.1.0 mod_pagespeed/1.6.29.2-"
```

Figured out definitely something is wrong with server (why is it hitting twice!).

Disabled and it worked fine

```
# Include conf/pagespeed.conf
# Include conf/pagespeed_libraries.conf
```

This issue was not happening in the dev site maybe because I have apache basic http authentication enabled (hence pagespeed was not caching it, just guessing).