# images not loaded with 503 resource not available

Tags: media

I have set up Redis (3.2.6) on Debian 8 and I am using redis 8.x-1.0-beta to make the connection. I am facing a strange error that happens every few days.

Drupal 8.2.7 will not serve few images (not all) and instead return a "503 resource not available" error in the browser inspector; I run `redis-cli flushall` to clear all cache and the images start loading again.

Upon inspection, the Redis cache is not full and Drupal log does not show anything strange.

Now Drupal gives me this error.

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\ServiceUnavailableHttpException: Image generation in progress. Try again shortly. in Drupal\image\Controller\ImageStyleDownloadController->deliver() (line 148 from /var/www/vhosts/alphanews.live/httpdocs/docroot/core/modules/image/src/Controller/ImageStyleDownloadController.php).

I suppose that the images get broken upon uploading and then Redis cache gets the broken image cached.

There are similar Drupal 7 reports about wrong server configuration in relation to HTTPS access to the images causing this kind of problem as it can be seen [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101897/image-generation-in-progress-try-again-shortly-503-service-unavailable) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1931456).

How do you prevent this error ? Is there any specific redis setup ? or is there any specific solution to this problem ?

Comment: @kiamlaluno How is this too broad ? there is 1 specific problem which needs solution ... if I had more information I would provide.

Comment: The question is too broad, not what you are describing. (_Does anyone have any experience with this error? **Any help** is appreciated._)

Comment: @kiamlaluno Its a problem that I did not know what the specific problem is or how its solved ... since there is no mention of it anywhere else on the internet or drupal.org for all I know it could be a bug either on drupal or redis, hence a patch might be what I am after or perhaps a configuration that I have missed ... I tried to make the question a little more specific but not sure ... if its still not ok I am giving up on this question ... or if you know how to make it specific please feel free to edit.

Comment: @kiamlaluno how is my question broader than this OPEN question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236561/view-scanning-wrong-template-file please explain