# View scanning wrong template file

Tags: 7, views, theming

I've inherited a Drupal 7 site that's having an issue. The field "date" appears on the test site, but not on prod, and the field "title" is linked on test, but not prod. On both sites, the "date" field shows up in views "preview."

Update: I've figured out as much as the view is scanning the wrong template file. There is a file with an identical name `learning/views-view-fields--block.tpl` that is being used in the view instead of `news/views-view-field--block`.

How does this happen and how can it be fixed (I'm new to Drupal view templates, so I apologize if there's a simple solution).

Comment: do you have any field permissions module in place?

Comment: @longboardnode nope, nothing per-field..

Comment: hmmm, is the testing db identical to prod? or have you tried cloning your prod db to local to see if the problem reproduces?

Comment: @longboardnode The date time field is definitely set for the content on prod. It even shows in the preview of the view (below the edit page)...

Comment: That doesn't answer the questions... do you regularly clone the prod database to dev? have you tried downloading the prod db to your local? you have to add a lot more info on this, otherwise this question is too localized and can't be answered.

Comment: Thank you @longboardnode. I thought the issue might be with the datetime module, but I've confirmed that it isn't (non-datetime fields are not working either). 

I've added some more detail above. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The most important thing right now is to determine how come your production is different than test... look at Japan's first comment on this DO post re dev workflow... do you routinely clone your database from prod to test and dev?

Comment: @longboardnode no, I do not. What makes me think the issue is not with the content is that: 1. the content on prod does have a value for date, 2. I was told the date field stopped working after some edits on the live server.

Comment: Ok try to compare the date modules and date field settings on live to test and see if you can find any differences in any of these settings. Other than that I can't offer more. I'd highly recommend to you to adopt the dev workflow mentioned by Jaypan above, without it you're going to be spinning your wheels endlessly. If you can't download the production database to your local and inspect it offline, and you don't clone prod to test/dev after deployments, then it is very difficult to debug issues.

Comment: Thanks  @longboardnode. I've found out that the view is scanning the wrong template file (see update above). Thanks for all your assistance! I actually don't see a comment from Japan, did you mean from this thread?, but I'll definitely be better about that!

Comment: Oops sorry Jillian here's the link to Jaypan's comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2323585#comment-9066929

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by going into structure->views->the-specific-view-causing-the-issue(News)->advanced->theme information, and found a more specific name for "Row style output," in this case `views-view-fields--news--block.tpl.php`.